# React native AlertIOS callback

Tags: react-native, alert

When I click the Cancel button, it shows "undefined is not an object". code shown as follow.

Update:

```
componentWillMount() {
    PushNotificationIOS.addEventListener('notification', this._onRemoteNotification);
}

_onRemoteNotification(notification) {
  AlertIOS.alert(
    'Push Notification Received',
    'Alert message: ' + notification.getMessage(),
    [{
      text: 'OK',
      onPress: null,
    },
    {
      text: 'Cancel',
      onPress: ()=>this.setState({key: value}),
    },
    ]
  );
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you're calling this alert in your component?

Comment: Updated. Please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want you can also simply `bind` your function and externalize it like that:

```
onAlertCancel() {
  this.setState({key: value});
}

AlertIOS.alert(
  'Push Notification Received',
  'Alert message: ' + notification.getMessage(),
  [{
    text: 'OK',
    onPress: null,
  },
  {
    text: 'Cancel',
    onPress: this.onAlertCancel.bind(this),
  },
  ]
);
}
```

Also don't forget to `bind` the main function to allow them to access to `this`, so:

`this._onRemoteNotification` became `this._onRemoteNotification.bind(this)`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried but it shows undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.onAlertCancel')

Comment: Ok I know why, in this line `PushNotificationIOS.addEventListener('notification', this._onRemoteNotification);` just bind the function like that: `this._onRemoteNotification.bind(this)`, that will bind the function to the class, so after that this would not be undefined anymore!

Comment: Fixed. Thank you very much. Is there any explanation on using bind ? when should I use and when it's not necessary?

Comment: By example in your code, you create a function pointer `this._onRemoteNotification` and you give this one to `PushNotificationIOS.addEventListener`, so when a notification is received your function `_onRemoteNotification` is going to be called from `PushNotificationIOS`, and that's will brake the value of `this` in your function. So, `bind` is here to solve this problem, when you `bind` a function `this` became a parameter of this one and can be use in the function. Each time you need to use `this` in a function just bind it to avoid this kinds of errors.

Comment: If you want to know more about this function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: Thanks for your info

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving this error because `this` is not defined inside `AlertIOS.alert`. You must reference your component before function call. Your code will look like this:

```
var self = this;

AlertIOS.alert(
  'Push Notification Received',
  'Alert message: ' + notification.getMessage(),
  [{
    text: 'OK',
    onPress: null,
  },
  {
    text: 'Cancel',
    onPress: ()=>self.setState({key: value}),
  },
  ]
);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried but it shows undefined is not an object (evaluating 'self.setState')